# Request Object ID - what is its max length? is there max length specified even?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

the Facebook app request API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1), returns/uses a **Request Object ID** that identifies the **Request Object**.

This **Request Object ID** is said to be a string, but does Facebook say what is the max length of this ID? Kind of hard to design a database without any idea of the max length ...